# User Defined Class Method in C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, scientific-computing

I am working on an exercise in the textbook, Scientific Computing in C++ by Francis and Whitely and cannot figure out how to correctly implement exercise 7.3.

Exercise: The goal is to learn about class inheritance by creating an abstract class that contains methods for solving ordinary differential equations.  The derived classes inherit this abstract class and are associated with specific algorithms for solving ODEs, like explicit Euler, RK4, etc.  Two of the methods in the abstract class are pure virtual, SolveEquation and RightHandSide.  The exercise requires you to use write the code for the derived class ForwardEuler, which implements the explicit Euler method.

Issue:  In the exercise, they ask you to "Derive a class called FowardEulerSolver that allows the user to specify the function RightHandSide", but RightHandSide is a member of a class, and I can't figure out how to let a user specify a class method in the main program, which is what I assume they are asking for.

Question:  Can someone explain the proper way in C++, if there is one, to allow a user to specify a class method?  Based on the way the way the base class is implemented in the book, it appears there must be some way to have a user define the RightHandSide function in the main program, and then call the SolveEquation method to solve the ODE associated with that RightHandSide function.

Here is the header for the abstract class given in the book.

```
class AbstractODESolver
{
    public:
        AbstractODESolver();
        double (*RHS)(double, double);
        void SetStepSize(double h);
        void SetTimeInterval(double t0, double t1);
        void SetInitialValue(double y0);
        void setRHS(double (*RHS)(double, double));
        double GetStepSize();
        double GetInitialTime();
        double GetFinalTime();
        double GetInitialValue();
        virtual double RightHandSide(double y, double t) = 0;
        virtual void SolveEquation(std::string filename) = 0;
        virtual ~AbstractODESolver();
    private:
        double stepSize;
        double initialTime;
        double finalTime;
        double initialValue;
};
```

And here is the header for the derived class.

```
class ForwardEulerSolver : public AbstractODESolver
{
    public:
        ForwardEulerSolver();
        double RightHandSide(double y, double t);
        void SolveEquation(std::string filename);
        virtual ~ForwardEulerSolver();
    private:
};
```

Comment: Have you read about `virtual` functions? Do you know what they do or how they are used?

Comment: The definition of `ForwardEulerSolver` that you provided already allowed the user to specify the behavior: it has been overwritten.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, I have read about virtual functions, and know that they allow the method of a base class to be overridden in the derived class.  I must have missed something since I don't see how that makes it clear how to make the RightHandSide function modifiable in the main program.

Comment: @faranwath Yes, in the header for ForwardEulerSolver, I have made it so that the RightHandSide function is overridden in the derived class.  My problem is that I don't know how to write the code that allows the user to specify what the RightHandSide is in the main program.  I only know how to write one RightHandSide method in ForwardEulerSolver.cpp and have that be the RightHandSide for all instances of the class.

Comment: @caburke Well, I think it's an odd question the one you were asked in the book. Take a look at `std::function`, it may provide what you're looking for.

Comment: @caburke _'My problem is that I don't know how to write the code that allows the user to specify what the RightHandSide is in the main program'_ This is why I have close voted that's unclear what you're asking. What exactly to yo mean with this? It makes no sense for me.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I mean that the user should be able to specify the RightHandSide function and that it should be possible to have different RightHandSide functions for different instances to the class.  My problem is that I don't know how to make a class method that a user of the class can define differently for different instances of the class.  I assume that is what the textbook asks for since they declare RightHandSide to be a virtual method.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This seems to be similar to what I need, but I need to be able to set RightHandSide to a specific function.  Is there a way to use this syntax to set RightHandSide equal to a function defined in the main program?  Something like 'x->RightHandSide = RHS;', possibly with function pointers?

Comment: @caburke I have tried to formulate an answer for what I get from your question and comments. Might be still on a completely wrong path!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there must be some way to have a user define the RightHandSide function in the main program, and then call the SolveEquation method to solve the ODE associated with that RightHandSide function.

It's still a bit unclear for me, what exactly you're asking for, but from your comments it sounds you want to have a user defined function executed within your abstract classes context. I think this is possible, but you'll need to change the interfaces a bit:

```
class AbstractODESolver
{
    public:
        AbstractODESolver();
        // ...
        void SolveEquation(std::string filename) {
             // Have an abstract implementation of the algorithm involving
             // a call to the RightHandSide() method.
        }
        virtual ~AbstractODESolver();

    protected:
        virtual double RightHandSide(double y, double t) = 0;
    private:
        double stepSize;
        double initialTime;
        double finalTime;
        double initialValue;
};
```

---

```
class ForwardEulerSolver : public AbstractODESolver
{
public:
    typedef double (*FnType)(AbstractODESolver*,double,double);

    ForwardEulerSolver(FnType fn_) : fn(fn_) { assert(fn); }
    virtual ~ForwardEulerSolver();
private:
    virtual double RightHandSide(double y, double t)
    {
        return (*fn)(this,y,t);
    }

    FnType fn;
};
```

If you're working in a [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) environment you can use an inline lambda function definition to get the necessary function pointer:

```
int main()
{
    ForwardEulerSolver::FnType rightHandSide = 
        [](AbstractODESolver* solver, double y, double t) { 
            // Replace with reasonable user implementation
            return 0.0; 
        }; 

    ForwardEulerSolver fwEulerSolver(rightHandSide);

    fwEulerSolver.SolveEquation("MyInput.txt");
}
```

For pre c++11 standard you can use a module private function definition to implement the wanted behavior

```
namespace {
    double RightHandSide(AbstractODESolver* solver, double y, double t) { 
        // Replace with reasonable user implementation
        return 0.0; 
    }
}

int main()
{

    ForwardEulerSolver fwEulerSolver(&RightHandSide);

    fwEulerSolver.SolveEquation("MyInput.txt");
}
```

This is more or less replicating, what's called the [Template Method Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method/cpp/1), but handling a special (edge) use case, to allow setting a user defined implementation function for a particular part of the algorithm.

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I want, but when I add in the C++ 11 code I get a compiler error.  I am using GCC 4.8.1 compiler and I have the "have g++ follow the C++11 standard ..." option checked in Codeblocks, but the 'ForwardEulerSolver(FnType fn_) fn(fn_) { assert(fn); }' line the second block of code results in a cascade of errors, "error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration", "error: ‘fn_’ has not been declared", "error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘fn’ with no type [-fpermissive]", etc.

Comment: @caburke Sorry I missed the `:` to start the member initializer list in the `ForwardEulerSolver()` constructor. I have a compilable version [here](http://ideone.com/dF37rX).

Comment: It works now!  I will have to review exactly what your code is doing, and it is probably more complicated than what the book expected, but it does work and seems to be fairly easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

You make your own `ForwardEulerSolver::RightHandSide` function.

You don't have to make anything special in the `main` function, just create an instance of the `ForwardEulerSolver` class and assign it to a pointer to `AbstractODESolver` and call the function. The compiler will handle the rest for you.

Comment: I probably haven't explained my question well enough, but will this allow RightHandSide to be different for different instances of the ForwardEulerSolver class?  My understanding is that every instance of this class should have a different RightHandSide, and then calling SolveEquation() will output the numerical solution to the ODE for that particular RightHandSide function.  I would have done this using a function pointer to a RHS function as an argument to SolveEquation, but the book apparently wants RightHandSide to be a member of the class, so that is why I am confused.